# Remove the link to a featured image if and only if it's not a gif

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a condition whereby:

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() ){
    return get_the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

However, I would like that condition to be valid for all images's extensions, except for `.gif`.

How can I achieve that?

My ultimate goal is not to be taken to the article when the featured image on the home is `.gif`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check the *mime type* of the *featured image*, then one way could be to use `get_post_thumbnail_id()` to get it's ID and then check the mime type with `get_post_mime_type()` :

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() && 'image/gif' !== get_post_mime_type( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
    return get_the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

where you return it for non-gifs.